# Save site as template in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, site-template

I have one SharePoint 2013 site, which I need to setup on another server.

In 2010 there was an option to save site as template in site actions, which is not there in 2013.

How can this be achieved? I am using team site template

Comment: the question you marked the anwser, i already mentioned in my reply....if you check the link all options are there....

Comment: even i marked yours as answer. :) thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open you Team Site in SharePoint Designer 2013.

In SharePoint Designer, under Sites tab select “Site Options”
 Find **SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled** in Site Properties
set to "true".

Now in your Publishing site navigate to `http://sitename/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx` and you would see the old Save Site as Template Page

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the Publishing site template then this option will not be available. Also if you have a team site with Publishing feature activate on it then this options will disappear.

Another thing, Save as Template option is not supported for publishing sites even if you are able to save it.

You can hack the url and directly go to this URL `http://sitename.com/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx`

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2492356

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0887cfe8-62a4-4eff-8d1b-9305f4a2c0ce/save-site-as-template-missing-sp2013?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: once template is saved, can be accessed from 
    http://mysitename/_catalogs/solutions/Forms/AllItems.aspx