# How to Import Sharepoint2013 site from the saved site template wsp?

Tags: site-collection, publishing-site, site-template, import

I have saved the site using the method explained in 
[Save site as template in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112891/save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-2013)

now , I want to import the site on another machine. how to achieve this?

Comment: How did you save the publishing site as a site template?

Comment: @Thomson: i saved using the method explained in  
"Save site as template in SharePoint 2013". the template is saved as .wsp file, which can be accessed from http://mysitename/_catalogs/solutions/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upload the WSP to the Solution Gallery in the Site Collection where you want to use your template and activate it. Once activated you should get a new template available when creating a new site.

If you want to create a new Site Collection using your template, you should create a Site Collection without choosing a template (the select template later option) and follow the steps I mentioned previously.