# How to export the Site and import the another server in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

is there possible to export the site or Team site in one server and import that site or teamsite in another server. I have used sharepoint 2013 and sharepoint designer 2013.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanna move a sub site or a site collection there is a little more to it..

First of all the servers need to be on the same patch level, meaning both SharePoint environments needs to be running on the same versions. Hence you can't move anything from a SharePoint servers that run on RTM to a server that runs on SP1. The versions **must** match. The same applies to any cumulative updates.

To move/export a site or sub site you will need to use PowerShell.

Secondly, to backup a sub site you need to use the `export-spweb` cmdlt. One of the most important parameter here is `-includeusersecurity`. The parameter make sure that all the sites permission are included in the export and make sure that all permissions are intact, as well as the data about your objects like modified by, created by etc. However, all the security groups that are available in the **whole** site collection will be added in the site collection that you choose to restore the sub site to.

The other important parameter is `-IncludeVersions`, which let's you choose what type of versions you will keep. You can choose to specify from any of the options below.

-Last major version for files and list items (default)
-The current version, either the last major version or the last minor version
-Last major and last minor version for files and list items
-All versions for files and list items

So a export command can look like this

```
Export-SPweb -identity "http://webapp/sites/siteCollection/subsiteYouWannaExport -Path "ExportPathLocation\ExportName.cmp" -includeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions All
```

[Export-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx)

This will create an export of the subsite with intact permissions and include all versions for your documents, list items, pages etc.

To import the export, you will need to create a new sub site of the **same** template on the new server and in the new location where you want your exported sub site to be.

After that you can import the subsite by using the cmdlt `import-spweb`.

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity "http://webapp/sites/sitecollection/newSubSite" -Path "ExportPathLocation\ExportName.cmp" -includeUserSecurity"
```

[Import-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx)

If you need to move a site collection to another server you need to create a new site collection on your new server and in the location where you want your site collection to be. Then you need to use the cmdlt `backup-spsite`.

It's a little bit easier because the permissions and versions are included in the backup. But the site collection still need to be of the same template on both servers.

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity "http://webapp/sites/SiteCollectionYouWannaExport" -Path "BackupPathLocation\BackupName.bak"
```

[Backup-SPSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx)

To import the site collection to your new server, use the cmdlt **restore-spsite**.

```
Restore-Spsite -Identity "http://webapp/sites/NewSiteCollection" -Path "BackupPathLocation\BackupName.bak"
```

[Restore-SPSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx)

There is a option to save a sub site as a template and include the content from the UI. I'm gonna quote [Waqas Sarwar MCSE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/21563/waqas-sarwar-mcse)'s answer from another thread.

> If you are using the Publishing site template then this option will not be available. Also if you have a team site with Publishing feature activate on it then this options will disappear.
>
> Another thing, Save as Template option is not supported for publishing
>   sites even if you are able to save it.
>
> You can hack the url and directly go to this URL
>   http://sitename.com/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx

The answer is from the following thread: [Save site as template in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112891/save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-2013).

[SharePoint Publishing feature does not support "Save Site as Template" option](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2492356)

Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

To export, use

```
Export-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp
```

To import, use

```
Import-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp
```

Details on additional command line attributes [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx).

Import is a bit picky, so you will get errors if you have some features activated on the source site that do not exist on the destination site.