# Installing a root App that will automatically install on newly created sites [Sharepoint 2013]

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, app, root

Haven't had much luck combing through countless pages, forums etc... to find out if it is possible to install an application such as InfoWise Ultimate Forms or Lightning Conductor in my root site and then have any subsequent sites that are generated have the application installed on that new site.

The main goal here is so that I won't have to manually install the same application on every subsite that is created. Ideally I would like an applications functionality available straight off the bat but is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked that the app should get installed automatically when a site is created, Then you should start thinking in terms of custom Site templates.

> **Truth:** You can push an app to app catalog . This will result in
>   availibilty of your app across all site collections in your Sharepoint
>   online. But you have to install the app manually in various site
>   collections based on your need.
>
> **Workaround:** you can install the app in one of the site collection and
>   then save this site as template. Later, whenever you need to create
>   other Sites, you can choose this custom site template.  **Site settings
>   -> under Site action look for "Save Site as Template" and select checkbox "Include content"**

*Note: this feature is available for team sites. for publishing site you can use SP designer for making templates. See this [Thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112891/save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-2013)*

[image]

**EDIT: Alternative way**
It seems using CSOM you can automate the Apps/Add-in installation. See this [msdn Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vesku/2015/11/20/automating-add-inapp-installation-to-sharepoint-sites-using-csom/). I hope this helps!

Comment: Sadly Site Templates doesn't work with the applications I need. Mainly Infowise Ultimate Forms.

Comment: ohh, have you tried with creating site backup and restore. It seems a limited option are there in SP online. See : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/734d9af0-baa0-44ca-bf7f-57d53686e811/backup-and-restore-sharepoint-online-site?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

Comment: pls refer my updated Answer

Comment: Absolutely spot on. This will save so much hassle. The MSDN blog shows you how to install the app and deploy it to all subsites.