# Can i make a SharePoint add-in which represents a remote event receiver available to all sub-sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver

when developing server-side event receiver, we can define the Scope for the server-side event receiver to be at the site level as follow:-

[image]

this will allow the ER to fire on the root site and the subsites. now when it comes to SharePoint add-ins which represent remote even receivers, seems we need to install the add-inn on each sub-site. so my question is if we can install the add-in on the root site and make the remote event receiver available to all the sub-sites, as in the server-side ER case?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below article to Automate add-in/app installation to SharePoint sites using CSOM:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vesku/automating-add-inapp-installation-to-sharepoint-sites-using-csom

Similar post:

[Installing a root App that will automatically install on newly created sites [Sharepoint 2013]](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221150/installing-a-root-app-that-will-automatically-install-on-newly-created-sites-sh)