# Need help with copying a SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-template, save-as-template

In a bit of a quandary over how to copy a SharePoint site.  I tried following the steps in this article, but I get an error telling me that the maximum total file size limit has been exceeded.

A work-around for this issue would be appreciated!

https://www.accuweaver.com/2010/11/05/how-to-copy-a-sharepoint-site/

Comment: is it a subsite or site collection level?

Answer (score 1):

You have to two options now, if it is subsite.

1. Export the site using the [export-spweb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/Export-SPWeb?view=sharepoint-ps) and then import it using [import-spweb](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/import-spweb?view=sharepoint-ps)
2. Use the pwoershell and change the max size limit to your site size.

   Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

   $webservice =[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService

   Get the current Maximum Size

   $webservice.MaxTemplateDocumentSize

   Set New Limit and update

   $webservice.MaxTemplateDocumentSize = 524288000 #500 MB

   $webservice.Update()

> Although the maximum template size in SharePoint 2010 or in SharePoint
>   2013 can be set to: 524288000 (500 MB), Always try to keep it in lower
>   than: 50 MB for better performance!

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/02/increase-list-template-maximum-size-in-sharepoint.html#ixzz53tPIEYH9

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to copy the Sharepoint site or is it simply that a List or Document Library has reached it's maximum limit?  If you really do need to copy the site, check out '[Save Site as Template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112891/save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint-2013)'.

For instance if it is a Document Library, maybe the number of documents is at the limit.

Otherwise if it is a list, they also have a limit of the number of items that a single list may contain - something like this picture of the List Settings screen for example:

[image: list view threshold picture]

If so, you could simply create a new Document Library or List.  For instance if your Project Document Library has 5000 documents (and this is the defined limit) and it contains `Project 1 - 1350` you could rename it as **Projects Document 1-1350**.  Then make a new Document Library called **Project Document 1351-x**